# How to disable default vertical scroll bar that comes in IE 7?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-7

I can see a vertical scroll bar without scroll when I open my IE 7.
I is not so weird to see but it is not obeying my web page rules.

I cannot see this kind of strange behavior in any other browser.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following CSS code is working fine. It disables the default vertical scroll bar in IE 7

```
html{
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's the standard behavior of the browser, I believe you shouldn't worry about it. Users of IE7 are used to the scrollbar being there. Even if there is a solution, you should let the browser behave as it usually does.